# How to sync apps with one Mac and 3 devices?

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone, ipad

We have 1 Mac, with 1 iTunes account, and 3 iOS devices.

Every time we sync one device, iTunes either spams it with ALL apps from ALL devices, OR it removes all of the apps from the device including all the data. Which is very annoying.

Someone told me there is a way to tell iTunes to keep separate track of the devices.

How can I setup iTunes such that it will not transfer all my iPhone-only apps to my iPad every time I sync? Basically I want the devices to be the "master". They give the direction which apps should be on the device, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you *exact* instructions (as don't have iTunes here) but there's a setting something along the lines of 'let me choose what to have on my device' as the iTunes default is to automatically copy everything (you might need to turn this off before seeing the other option).